# Shell and MySQL custom connection success message

Tags: mysql, shell

How can I print a custom success message if connected to mysql via shell? Instead of displaying mysql error messages.
Something like this

```
if [ "$mysql_connected" ]; then
  echo "connected"
  # do mysql stuff
else
  echo "connection failed"
fi
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use exit status as shown below:

```
mysql -uroot -pabc -e"show databases;"
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
echo "success";
else
echo "failed to connect";
fi
```